# How to check if the checkbox is not checked using Ajax and PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following checkbox:

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="yes" id="checkBox">
```

it's one of the form elements , I send the form data to a PHP file using Ajax:

```
var check = $('#checkBox').val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "file.php",
    data: {check:check},
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Then in the file.php:

```
$check = $_POST['check'];
if( !isset($check) OR $check !== "yes" ){
    echo "Not checked";
}
```

But that condition will be always false , As the value will always be set and = `yes`

So how to check that the checkbox is not checked?

Comment: _“So how to check that the checkbox is not checked?”_ - by checking the actual _checked_ status of the checkbox to begin with, instead of its _value_ …?

Comment: @CBroe , And how exactly to do that ?

Comment: if ($('#checkBox').attr("checked")) {}

Comment: _“And how exactly to do that ?”_ - please do your own research before asking about banalities like this, as if there was a reasonable expectation that you are the absolutely first person ever on this world to try and figure that out. Typing something trivial like “javascript get checkbox state” into Google should not be too much for you to handle on your own.

Answer (score 3):

Here we need to use [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method to check that checkbox is checked or not.

```
var check = false;
if($('#checkBox').prop('checked') == true ){
    check = $('#checkBox').val();
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "file.php",
    data: {check:check},
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You post the value of your checkedbox (checked or not).

Try this:

```
var check = $('#checkBox:checked').val();
```

It will return `yes` or `undefined`.

To test if the checkbox is checked, you can test on the length:

```
var isChecked = $('#checkBox:checked').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

This return true if checked

```
var check = $('#checkBox:checked').length > 0;
```

This return '1' if checked

```
 var check = $('#checkBox:checked').length;
```